# Non-Perfect Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am searching for fields that are not perfect. My guess is that $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$ as well as $\text{Frac}(\mathbb{F}_p[t^p])$ are both non-perfect fields. Is that correct? ($\text{Frac}$ denoting the Field of Fractions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right. In the first example, $t$ is not a $p^{\text{th}}$th power. In the second one, $t^p$ is not a $p^{\text{th}}$ power.